# Using custom control's alias in XAML

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, custom-controls

In a WPF (Silverlight) UserControl I have lots of custom control instances:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:My="clr-namespace:MyProject;assembly=MyAssembly" Name="uc1" >
...
<Grid x:Name="grid1">   
...   
  <My:CustControl x:Name="name1" />   
  <My:CustControl x:Name="name2" />   
  <My:CustControl x:Name="name3" />   
... 
</Grid>
```

In **MyProject** I have not only the `CustControl` implemented, but also the `CustControl1`, the `CustControl2`, the `CustControl3` and the like. Sometimes, I have to use another custom control type in the UserControl. Can I have only one place for changing custom control's name instead of changing it in all the numerous references in the XAML?

In other words, can I use an alias for those multiple custom control references inside my XAML and one place where I define the real CustomControl class' name for that alias?

Or maybe some other approach for solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a simple empty wrapper class, which would inherit the control you currently use. Then in XAML you would use this wrapper instead of the specific CustControl. At any time, you could change the base class for the wrapper at one single place.

But I must say: this design stinks. Are you sure you couldn't solve this issue with global styles/templates for one CustControl class?